# AppDelegate to SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I had an old project that I was working which doesn't has the sceneDelegate. My AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions looks like :

```
import Firebase
import customFramework 
    
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
        var window: UIWindow?
        
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            
            // Create window
            window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            
            
            
            customFrameworkManager.shared.start()
            
            return true
        }
    .
    .
    .
```

I wanted to transform this code and hence decided to create a new fresh project but now there is an implementation of scene Delegate instead. I tried changing my func scene (willConnectTo) which looked like :

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
            // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
            // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
            // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            
            self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
            
         
                }
        customFrameworkManager.shared.start()
    }
```

But the customFramework is not launching in on the application. Can anyone suggest what wrong am I doing here. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like .start() should be getting called. In fact, it should be getting called twice. Are you sure that's not the case?

Comment: @ChrisForeman No it isn't getting called out there. I have removed it from AppDelegate and put it into sceneDelegate. But it is not getting called. It is supposed to create a new window on top of the current application.

Answer (score 0):

In your sceneDelegate I don't see the rootViewController, try like this:

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
let controller = ViewController()
window.rootViewController = controller
self.window = window
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
customFrameworkManager.shared.start()
```